# wrong packages opened in spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

im currently using xubuntu 14.04 LTS, with an installation of python 2.7.6 in `/usr/bin/` and an anaconda (python 2.7.11) installation in `/home/carlo/anaconda2`

upon running Spyder, i'll get a

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
```

also inside spyder, i'll get this:

```
>>>sys.executable
'/home/carlo/anaconda2/bin/python'
```

which means im running the right python executable. but doing this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__
''/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc''
```

(i think) means that spyder is somehow not picking up the packages installed in my anaconda installation (`1.10.4` vs `1.9.2`)

i already tried appending this to my `.bashrc`

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/carlo/anaconda2/bin/"
```

and this to my `.profile`

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/carlo/anaconda2/bin/"
```

but somehow i still get the same problem.

entering `sys.path` in spyder gets:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/pkgs', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
```

which i think means it's already there, it's just that it's not the default path.

if it means anything, running python from a terminal gives me the "normal" situation. numpy is at `1.10.4` instead of the `1.9.2` in `/usr/bin/` and my excutable is in the anaconda directory.

so yeah, would like to ask help on how to proceed from here. thanks.

EDIT:
also,

```
/home/carlo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/carlo/anaconda2/pkgs
```

are included in the PYTHONPATH Manager.

UPDATE:
running spyder from the application finder gets me python version 2.7.6, but with the updated modules (numpy 1.10.4). while running `conda run spyder` or `spyder &` in the terminal gets me python version 2.7.11 and the updated modules